# Cancelling firebase notification from app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending following payload for notification:

```
var message = {
    data: {
    user: sendData.from,
    body: sendData.message,
    sentto: sendData.to,
    gcm_username: sendData.from
    },
    android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
            title: 'Yeni mesaj aldınız',
            body: sendData.from + ' size bir mesaj gönderdi',
            tag: sendData.from,
            sound: 'default',
            channelId: 'messages'
            }
        },
    token: deviceToken
 };
```

But sometimes i have to cancel certain notification when user opens the app from the app icon.

I tried following code:

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public Notification deleteNotificationByTag(String senderCode) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        StatusBarNotification[] barNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
        for(StatusBarNotification notification: barNotifications) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getActiveNotification: " + notification.getTag());
            if (notification.getTag() != null && notification.getTag().equals(senderCode)) {
                notificationManager.cancel(notification.getId());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But `notification.getId()` method is always returning 0 value. So cancel is not working. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag to cancel the notification as follows:

```
public void cancel (String tag, int id);
```

So even if the id is 0, it should work if the tag is unique.

Comment: I am sending notification from server not creating locally.

Comment: You can add a type in your payload and check your payload for that type. If it's there , delete it

Comment: You can use above methode by passing false ID and then cancel that notification by false ID. may be this will work

Comment: @TolgayToklar I knew you are sending from server, but firebase gives you a RemoteMessage which I guess then you display using NotificationManager. At that time I was asking you to create the id using sent time for example. If you want to cancel before displaying then I got it wrong.

Comment: No, if app is not in running(in foreground or background) android is not calling RemoteMessage service, it just handles notification by itself.

Comment: You are right on that. But this was not clear from the question. There is one more option, which clears all notifications. Like notificationManager.cancelAll();

Comment: I've updated the answer, have a look, if it works for you.

Comment: Using the tag works

Answer (score 0):

One option is to send data messages and create notifications with id manually and You can cancel messages as per your requirements.

Comment: But people saying if the phone is in doze mode, onMessageReceived won't be called.

Comment: According to documentation Network access is suspended in doze mode non data notification will not be delivered as well. You can use high priority notifications
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: you can check doze checklist and doze restrictions on this link https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby